# Update a column in one dataframe with a condition from another dataframe in Python without For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have one data frame which is loads a central file. New files are monthly updated here. Since there are few missing columns in the file which is copied into the data frame, I created a mapping dataframe which adds values to the dataframe when condition is met for the missing columns.

Below is the central file example:

```html
ID Region Country Code User Order Price
1  Germany  ABC 2342545
2  Italy  DEF 5464545
3  USA  GHI 3245325
4  India  JKL 676565
5  Mexico  MNO 3443252
6  China  PQR 565445
7  Germany  STU 765765
8  Mexico  VWX 564566
9  China  YZA 346534
10  India  BCD 5675765
```

This is my mapping file for missing Region and Code

```html
Country Region Code
Germany EU 1
Italy EU 2
USA America 3
India Asia 4
Mexico America 5
China Asia 6
```

Here is the expected output:

```html
ID Region Country Code User Order Price
1 EU Germany 1 ABC 2342545
2 EU Italy 2 DEF 5464545
3 America USA 3 GHI 3245325
4 Asia India 4 JKL 676565
5 America Mexico 5 MNO 3443252
6 Asia China 6 PQR 565445
7 EU Germany 2 STU 765765
8 America Mexico 5 VWX 564566
9 Asia China 6 YZA 346534
10 Asia India 4 BCD 5675765
```

What I have done is to use for loops with iterrows() to update the values in the data frame.

The problem is it is super slow and it takes about an hour or more to update about 60,000 records.

here is my code:

```
        for central_update_index, central_update_row in central_bridge_file.iterrows():
        print('index: ', central_update_index)
        for bridge_match_index, bridge_match_row in central_bridge_matching_file.iterrows():
            if bridge_match_row['Country'] == central_update_row['Country']:
                if central_update_row['Country / Company (P2)'] == bridge_match_row['Country']:
                    central_bridge_file.loc[central_update_index, 'Code'] = \
                        bridge_match_row['Code']
                    central_bridge_file.loc[central_update_index, 'Region'] = bridge_match_row[
                        'Region']
```

Can someone help me in how can I write a lambda statement or something that could do it in mins?

Comment: You could try iterating using `itertuples` instead, it's a very small change code wise but usually results in quite good speed up

Comment: @Nathan: Ok I will try that I am actually using it in another loop, but what could be more useful is to have a one-liner statement, I have seen and used one within the same data frame but I could not create one across 2 data frames.

Comment: Please include your sample data as text, and also include your expected output.

Comment: are the empty fields empty strings or nans?

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: @luigigi: they are empty string which needs to be filled with the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give df,

```
   ID  Region  Country  Code User  Order Price
0   1     NaN  Germany   NaN  ABC      2342545
1   2     NaN    Italy   NaN  DEF      5464545
2   3     NaN      USA   NaN  GHI      3245325
3   4     NaN    India   NaN  JKL       676565
4   5     NaN   Mexico   NaN  MNO      3443252
5   6     NaN    China   NaN  PQR       565445
6   7     NaN  Germany   NaN  STU       765765
7   8     NaN   Mexico   NaN  VWX       564566
8   9     NaN    China   NaN  YZA       346534
9  10     NaN    India   NaN  BCD      5675765
```

and df_map,

```
   Country   Region  Code
0  Germany       EU     1
1    Italy       EU     2
2      USA  America     3
3    India     Asia     4
4   Mexico  America     5
5    China     Asia     6
```

You can `merge` these two dataframes on 'Country':

```
df[['ID','Country','User','Order Price']].merge(df_map)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Country User  Order Price   Region  Code
0   1  Germany  ABC      2342545       EU     1
1   7  Germany  STU       765765       EU     1
2   2    Italy  DEF      5464545       EU     2
3   3      USA  GHI      3245325  America     3
4   4    India  JKL       676565     Asia     4
5  10    India  BCD      5675765     Asia     4
6   5   Mexico  MNO      3443252  America     5
7   8   Mexico  VWX       564566  America     5
8   6    China  PQR       565445     Asia     6
9   9    China  YZA       346534     Asia     6
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it didn't update anything. Do you think I should mention only Country or all the columns other than the one to be updated?

Comment: Well, that command isn't inplace you need to reassign back to df.  Try this, `df=df[['ID','Country','User','Order Price']].merge(df_map)`  Does the output look correct in this answer?

Comment: Good Answer works really well, only thing, I need to mention all the column names I want to keep for the final dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to totally replace the `Region` and `Code` columns in your data, you can do merge:

```
df = (df.drop(['Region','Code'], axis=1)
        .merge(mapping, on='Country', how='left')
     )
```

If you only want to update those columns, e.g. keeping the old values, then

```
mapping = mapping.set_index('Country')

for c in ['Region', 'Code']:
    df[c] = df[c].fillna(df['Country'].map(mapping[c]))
```

Output:

```
   ID   Region  Country  Code User  Order Price
0   1       EU  Germany   1.0  ABC      2342545
1   2       EU    Italy   2.0  DEF      5464545
2   3  America      USA   3.0  GHI      3245325
3   4     Asia    India   4.0  JKL       676565
4   5  America   Mexico   5.0  MNO      3443252
5   6     Asia    China   6.0  PQR       565445
6   7       EU  Germany   1.0  STU       765765
7   8  America   Mexico   5.0  VWX       564566
8   9     Asia    China   6.0  YZA       346534
9  10     Asia    India   4.0  BCD      5675765
```

Comment: What do you mean by mapping?